# C# Use WebClient.UploadFile(string, string) to upload to a Apache & PHP webserver

Tags: .net, php, file-upload, webclient

The C# WebClient.UploadFile(string, string) sample on MSDN shows how to make it work with an ASPX page handling the upload. However I have a Apache server with PHP set up to handle my subversion repos. I have very little web programming knowledge, but would like to know...

Can my Apache/PHP web server handle a file from a c# client using WebClient.UploadFile() and can someone give me a small example of what to do...

I know it's a n00b request, but any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Redshirt: You might want to consider changing the question, as it doesn't have anything to do with C# or .NET.  The HTTP file POST operation is standardized, so it's not something specific to the client, but rather, the server.

Comment: I was thinking of leaving it as-is, that way any .net programmer having the same issue would stumble upon it. If I change it, it implies that the user already knows that POST is standardized, which I did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [section of the PHP documentation on handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) is what you are looking for.

The mechanism for [handling file uploads over HTTP is standardized in RFC1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html), so it doesn't matter whether you use .NET or another type of client, they will all do adhere to the protocol.